# Adding selected *sentences* for next occurrence

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, pycharm

In IntelliJ IDEs, I can add any duplicate words by using the 'Add selected text for next occurrence' key shortcut. When multiple words are selected simultaneously, I can then change all of them at once using the IdeaVim plugin and `ciw` key presses.

However, I haven't been able to do this successfully for sentences. For example, if I select a group of text between double quotes: `" hello there "`, what ends up happening is that I will be able to select/highlight duplicate groups of `hello there`, but pressing any key results in me only updating the first selection of `hello there` and not the other selections.

I do realize that I can achieve the same effect simply by doing a find/replace through the entire page, but I like the convenience of adding an occurrence one at a time with just a press of a button. Any suggestions?

Comment: Macroses? Record / run a macro once, and then simply re-run it at occurrences if needed "with just a press of a button" (`nnoremap Q @q<CR>`, `xnoremap Q :normal @q<CR>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the behavior you mentioned. However if you are looking for a method that have the visual effect similar to the Intellij, you may need to use the plugin for vim, such as [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).

Here are some vim's ways to do that:

**Next Occurence + Redo Last Command**:

1. `/` to search for all occurence (/ hello there )
2. `n` to navigate to next occurence
3. `v` and arrow key/`l` to select region
4. Substitute region with `s` or delete text under region with `x`
5. `n` for next occurence and `.` (dot) to redo last command and repeat `n` + `.`

**MACRO**:

1. `/` to search for all occurence (/ hello there )
2. `qq` to start recording macro to key <kbd>q</kbd>
3. Do step 2-4 from previous method
4. `q` to stop recording macro
5. `@` then `q` to apply the macro from key <kbd>q</kbd>

Note: If you want to repeat step 5 n times, simply append a number before `@` (ex. `5@q` to apply macro 5 times. If there are only 4 occurence, then macro will only be applied 4 timers.)

**Find and Replace**:

`:%s/ hello there /new value/g` to globally replace " hello there " to "new value"

To replace the occurrence in certain place, use visual block `v` to select the block then `:'<,'>s/ hello there /new value/g` to replace only in selected area